# how use super in django tables2 render_*

Tags: django, django-tables2

i create new Column and add customize render as below

```
class PriceColumn(django_tables2.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float):
            self.attrs['td']['title'] = f'{round(value, 2):,}'
            return number_convertor_to_milion(value)
        return '---
```

then i used it for field

```
weekly_returns = PriceColumn(verbose_name=_('Weekly Returns'))

def render_weekly_returns(self, value,**kwargs):
    final_result = value*100
    // i want to call super().render() like below
    return super().render(final_result,**kwargs)
```

i want to call `super` as in code writed but gives error

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'render'
```

how can do this?

Comment: Your first render method is missing a closing quote, but I'll guess that's just missed in cut/paste. In any case, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: i edit post and added error. thanks for note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `super()` is referring to the class it's in, which is the `MyTable(tables.Table)` class, not the intended `PriceColumn(Column)` class.

You can fix one of 2 ways, call to the Class method directly;

```
def render_weekly_returns(self, value,**kwargs):
    final_result = value*100
    return PriceColumn.render(final_result,**kwargs)
```

or I would probably recommend just adding the return method instructions into your `render_weekly_returns()` method as it's going to be easier to read in the future.

```
def render_weekly_returns(self, value,**kwargs):
    final_result = value*100
    if isinstance(final_result, int) or isinstance(final_result, float):
        self.attrs['td']['title'] = f'{round(final_result, 2):,}'
        return number_convertor_to_milion(final_result)
    return '---'
```

Comment: thanks. not exactly but first answer solved my problem